# How to setup navigation gestures in Android Oreo?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, gestures

In my previous RedMi phone, I could swipe from the left to move back, swipe from bottom to go to the home screen, and swipe and hold from the bottom to get to the multitasking view.

However, in my latest Asus pure Oreo phone, I can't seem to find such a setting. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Not a part of Android natively. Some launchers /apps/mods can do this

Comment: @beeshyams Right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this gesture navigation functionality is not a part of Android Oreo natively. Some launches/apps/mods could do this, but not natively.

(Based on the comments)